# Not able to extract data from JSONB Column in postgres

Tags: postgresql, heroku, jsonb

I have a table called Payments, in that one column called meta_data, that is jsonb type

and when I query that column in psql, getting this below format.

```
"{\"description\":\"Payment\",\"country\":\"US\",\"connected_account_id\":\"acct_Fp8aFJvDnp\",\"payment_method\":\"card\"}"
```

And I was trying to extract the each key, for example the below query

```
select id, payments.meta_data->'description' as desc from payments where id=1
```

But I am getting null value for the desc column

Is there anything wrong here? I tried both `->` and `->>`

Postgres verision is  11.19, Using Heroku.

Comment: How does your environment differ from [this one](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kdshDQys2pHjbUQXQwzP6a/0)?

Comment: thanks @lemon, If you run this query select id, payments.meta_data as desc from payments where id=1, in the fiddle you will get this {"description":"Payment","country":"US","connected_account_id":"acct_Fp8aFJvDnp","payment_method":"card"}

But when I run this in my postgres I am getting this as  "{\"description\":\"Payment\",\"country\":\"US\",\"connected_account_id\":\"acct_Fp8aFJvDnp\",\"payment_method\":\"card\"}"

so I think this saves as text right?

Comment: Yeah your json is not well formatted, because you're using extra double quotes at beginning and end, and your escapes on quotes are not needed. That's your issue.

Comment: Is there anyway I can convert this to jsonb, I tried payments.meta_data::JSON->>'description', but that doesn't work

Comment: I resolved by this code (payments.meta_data #>> '{}')::jsonb -> 'description'

thanks @lemon